# Colors change on external monitor when I close the lid

Tags: display, colors

I have an external monitor (Dell S2415H) connected to my laptop (Dell Inspiron 7559) through HDMI.

I refer to the external monitor only:

The colors show fine when the lid is open, but the picture becomes dimmer or yellowish when when I close the lid.

It's like Windows 10 loads a new color profile/scheme, but everywhere I checked is the same in both situations.

Here are two images I took with a mobile phone, in which the difference is pretty clear:

Good colors, white is real white
[image: Good colors, white is real white]

Bad colors, white is a bit yellow
[image: Bad colors, white is a bit yellow]

Do you know a solution? Maybe it's not what I think it is, like a config value somewhere else?

P.S
I conclude that it's Windows doing it because the only difference is if the lid is open or closed. The monitor's preset mode stays 'Standard'.

Comment: Windows can assign a color profile to your monitor. Perhaps when the lid is closed, windows changes the color profile based on the other monitor being active. You can find these settings in the Settings App, System, Display, Advanced Display Settings, Color Management.

Comment: Thanks @LPChip but I've just Checked again and can't find anything suspicious. Other ideas?

Comment: Isn't there some command-line app that aggregates all my display settings into a single textual output so I can post it here?

Comment: Post or compare between the two states/situations.

Comment: I have this exact problem with macOS and saw the color profiles are the same between the two scenarios.

Comment: Is windows night mode off, sometimes it kicks in after you close the lid.